# Time complexity for getting a row with max value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization, indexing

I would like to fetch a row with a minimum value of a myDate column. To do that I use the following query:

```
select * from (select * from table where processed = 'N'
order by myDate) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Is it possible to create an index(es) that will make this query to be of O(1) time complexity in Oracle: just pick first row from not processed rows with minimal date (something like a btree index divided in two parts as the `processed` column may have only to values 'Y' or 'N').

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with an index on (myDate, processed), you would be able to retrieve the one row directly. Not O(1) (a btree does not offer that), but much better than the O(n) of a full table scan.

The column order in that index is important. You usually want it first ordered by myDate, and within that switch by that flag (but see below).

Also note that if the "first" (ordered by myDate) thousands of entries all have `processed=Y` the index scan will still take (a little) time to skip all those (in the index, not going to the table). Worst case will still be O(n) if this applies to *all* entries (then it will be a full index scan).

If that turns out to be a problem, you could switch the index column order to (processed, myDate). Then you'd effectively have two B-tree indexes, one for Y and one for N.